# Upgrading Cloud function from Parse-server 2.0 to 3.0

Tags: parse-platform, es6-promise, parse-server, parse-cloud-code

I am in the middle of upgrading my Parse-server 2.0 Cloud functions to 3.0.

One of the functions working in 2.0 is:

```
Parse.Cloud.define("countOfObservations", function(request, response) {
    var query = new Parse.Query("GCUR_OBSERVATION");
    
    query.count({
      success: function(count) {
        // The count request succeeded. Show the count
        response.success(count);
      },
      error: function(error) {
        response.error("GCUR_OBSERVATION table lookup failed");
      }
    });
});
```

As the Parse-server 3.0 has removed `response` and leveraged native promises or async/await for asynchronous validation. I tried to rewrite the function as below.

```
Parse.Cloud.define("countOfObservations", (request) => {
    var query = new Parse.Query("GCUR_OBSERVATION");
    var countOfObs = 0;
    query.count({ useMasterKey: true }).then( (count) => {
        countOfObs = count;
        console.log("*** count=" + countOfObs);
        return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
            if (countOfObs >= 0)
                return resolve(countOfObs);
            else
                return reject();
        })
    });
});
```

When I called the function from client, it returned `{}` instead of `{"result":2882}` that I'd expected. However, the console did print *`** count=2882`.

How can I make the function work again using native promises?

Answer (score 0):

The reason it returns an empty object is because your function does not wait for `query.count` to complete and immediately returns with `undefined`.

You can write `return await query.count(...).then(...);` or even better, transform the whole function into Promise syntax and save some code lines. The Parse Team has developed a helpful [migration guide](https://github.com/parse-community/parse-server/blob/master/3.0.0.md) with examples to make the transition easier for you.

Then this would be all you need:

```js
Parse.Cloud.define("countOfObservations", async (request) => {
    const query = new Parse.Query("GCUR_OBSERVATION");
    const count = await query.count({ useMasterKey: true });
    console.log("*** count=" + count);
    return {"count": count};

    // or if you really need to reject:
    // return count >= 0 ? Promise.resolve(count) : Promise.reject();
});
```

Comment: Thanks @Manuel. I tried your code but it didn't work. The console printed "*** count=[object Promise]" and the client output was "{"result":{"count":{}}}".

Comment: Right, I added the async / await, please try again.